# In Git for windows "git bash", how to "print working directory" in Windows path format that is usable by cmd and Windows explorer?

Tags: windows, git, bash, git-for-windows

When using Git for Windows "git bash" on Windows, how to conveniently print the working directory in Windows path representation, e.g.

```
D:\foo\bar
```

similar to using 'pwd' to get the Unix representation

```
/d/foo/bar/
```

such that the path can be read by Windows explorer and cmd console?

Comment: Well, you can use `pwd -W`, but it uses forward slash, this is probably the closest you'll get. You can always do `cmd.exe /c cd`.

Comment: Thanks @Lasse, `pwd -W` is fit for my use-cases on Windows explorer and cmd console. I didn't realize they accept forward slash too. I really want to take your comment as answer.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In Git Bash:

```
$ cmd //c cd
C:\Program Files\Git
```

Note the double slash. And for forward slashes, as mentioned in the comments:

```
$ pwd -W
C:/Program Files/Git
```

Comment: Thanks @vestlen, single slash `cmd /c cd` also works. Why double slash ?

Comment: @yhd.leung On my box at least, using the single slash leaves you sitting in the cmd shell. Using the double slash prints the directory and then exits cmd, returning you to the bash shell.

Comment: To turn the slashes to back-slashed with `pwd -W`, just use: `pwd -W | sed 's,/,\\,g'`